# The right way to Architecting an Application with CoreOS and multiple Docker Containers

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, coreos

I am attempting to correctly set up a suite of applications and services which are currently built as Docker Containers. All of which relate to an overall application/service/ecosystem.

The services are be something along the lines of:

- A public API Server
- Data-store (rethinkDB)
- Web Application 1
- Web Application 2
- Public Forum
- Micro service 1
- Micro service 2
- Etc....

This will be hosted on a cloud service, or possible multiple services such as DigitalOcean.

CoreOS seems to be the most integrated way that buys into this philosophy but I am unsure if I understand the correct way to set up the stack correctly.

The main language used is JavaScript (nodeJS).

Problems and questions I face are:

1) Some Web applications need to be mapped to their own subdomains (nginx reverse proxy as a container, etcd's built-in solution, kubernetes????)

2) RethinkDB Needs to write information across all clusters reliably and near instantaneously (this is game-related, so DB's out of sync can cause issues). Is this possible across coreos clusters?

3) Can I host this on one singular server?... Should I?

Are there some good resources out there? I have read through documentation upon documentation, but the quickly changing and opinionated posts are not giving a clear answer as to how to start and solve some obvious issues. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Great questions!  It's super confusing I agree.  I've been making some progress on grok'ing the ecosystem by breaking it down into individual spikes and goals.

Advice is dangerous but here we go anyway.

"multiple clouds" - I'd probably stick with one unless you want to run a bunch of VPN links or have some use case that you want to support.  If you want to connect two clouds, it's possible.  We run something like this setup at work (colo + amazon).  It's fine although you have to manage a tunnel connection.  If this is a single app, I'd probably just stick it in DO and use auth/public keys for single services.

For example: servers by default in digital ocean, use authentication to S3 for archiving/hosting/images whatever.  No need for a tunnel, S3 is public.

Digital Ocean has coreos support baked in but doesn't have true private networks.  That means you need to protect yourself with `iptables` and then possibly rely on flannel.  More [here from digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/the-docker-ecosystem-networking-and-communication).

Your other questions:

1. Good example of subdomains with coreos: [this whole video series is great](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4215szNHlC4)
2. Your database is going to control locking.  I wouldn't think this has anything to do with coreos.  Rethinkdb uses networking for its distributed features, it doesn't know or care what it's actually in.  There are other things to consider though, more related to the networking/flannel thing above.  You need to be able to link rethinkdb nodes.  So this is more of a config/tutorial gotcha, not an architecture/safety question.  I'm going to be doing a blog post soon about running a rethinkdb toy cluster with docker.  It should act the same.
3. You probably should not host everything but I have no idea what load/traffic/requirements/anything you are imagining.  Although with fleet or other cluster orchestration tools in place, it won't matter!  Imagine a bunch of slots.

There are better images of this on the coreos website or the youtube series linked above:

```
machine 1
[ ]  [ ]  [ ]  [ ]  [ ]  [ ]

machine 2
[ ]  [ ]  [ ]  [ ] 

machine 3
[ ]  [ ]  [ ]  [ ] [ ]  [ ]  [ ]  [ ]
```

Containers take up slots on your machines.  You don't really care about machines, they are just resources.  You control this through some high level declarative cluster orchestration tool.  This is what the end game of cluster orchestration is all about and then you can move on to more lofty goals like auto-scaling etc ...

Of course you need a bunch of infrastructure in place and your app needs to be tolerant of this type of environment (no ips hardcoded, use ENV variables etc).

Break it into chunks.  Don't try to design everything.  Make a list of tools and their jobs / world view / problem its solving.

- Digital Ocean: colocation with coreos support (basically an image and cloud-config templates)

  - You are done and successful with this when: you have a minimum number of odd nodes (3/5/7/+) running coreos and etcd.
- CoreOS: runs docker images and has built in tools for higher level goals like cluster orchestration and service discovery

  - You are done and successful with this when: Etcd is started successfully and you can see a list of machines through fleet.  For the automatic subdomains feature you want: dynamic load balancing is taking place (you can scale up and basically DNS reacts).  You also know when you are done with this because any new app or microservice that comes along is stupid simple to support.
- Docker: a container format - your app needs to be in this somehow already.  You probably need tools to rebuild these too.

  - Done when: images rebuild themselves from commits to master and get tested in a CI service with docker support (if desired)
- fleet: declarative cluster orchestration (kubernetes)

  - Done when: you can control the scale of apps explicitly (not through implicit rube goldberg machinery) using fleetctl or whatever tool you want.  *Memcached!  Run on 5 nodes!  Go!*

I hope this is helpful.  I see that this is an old question.  Maybe you've moved on.  I just wanted to answer this for myself.  Maybe others can correct/help/expand-upon my answer too.